# Parte de mi código CSS no se aplica en mi código HTML ( dentro de un codigo PHP )

Tags: php, html, css

Estoy trabajando un un Formulario en HTML ( que a su vez esta dentro de un código PHP ) y los cambios en el apartado "form" de mi css no se hacen visibles en el proyecto, pero los cambios en "body" y "html" del css si se efectúan con éxito.

Adjunto mis lineas de texto HTML y CSS:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="URF-8">
  <title>Connect to API</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSSGoogleSheets.css">

</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <input type=text name="clientid" placeholder="&#128274; Clien ID"><br><br>
    <input type=text name="secretclientid" placeholder="&#128274; Secret Client ID"><br><br>
    <input type=text name="redirecturi" placeholder="&#128274; Redirect Uri"><br><br>
    <input type=text name="apiname" placeholder="&#128274; API Name"><br><br>
    <input type=text name="apikey" placeholder="&#128274; API key"><br><br>
    <input type=submit value="ingresar">
  </form>

  


</body>

</html>
```

```css
html{
background-color: lightgrey;
}

body{
font-family: sans-serif;
text-align: center;
background-color: lightgrey;
}

form{
margin: auto;
width: 50%;
max-width: 500px;
background: #F3F3F3;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Cualquier posible solución es de ayuda, recién estoy empezando en el mundo de la programación, se agradece la paciencia ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estoy probando tu código y el estilo `css` se aplica bien en el `form`. Probablemente te esté quedando en memoria cache el archivo `css` sin aplicar los cambios. Te recomiendo que actualices la pagina apretando `ctrl+f5`, esto debería borrar la caché. Si no funciona, dirigite a `http://tupagina/tucodigocss.css` y ahí vas a poder ver si los cambios se aplicaron o no. Si no se aplicaron, `ctrl+f5`.

Comment: Para evitar estos problemas recomiendo siempre comprobar los cambios en ventanas de incógnito.

Comment: Otra opción es instalar la extensión "Clear All Cache" o alguna similar. Hacen lo que necesitas con un solo click.

Comment: Ahí actualice la pagina con ctrl+f5 y se arreglo. Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Todavía tengo que esperar para poner la respuesta como correcta, pero en cuanto me deje lo hago.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el feedback. Cuando empieces con javascript, vas a tener algunos dolores de cabeza con estas cosas. No siempre ctrl+f5 arreglan el problema, desconozco porque. Por eso siempre que no veas cambios, tené en cuenta abrir una ventana incógnito, una extensión que limpie la caché, o cambiar de navegador. Saludos y suerte en el mundo del desarrollo :)

Answer (score 0):

cheque tu codigo y esta excelente , hay aveces que pasan con los navegadores que no realizan el cambio, entonnces lo que debes de hacer es, eliminar la cache o la cookis del navegador, o simplemtente abre tu pagina co otro navegador como firefoox,safari etc

Comment: Ya me respondieron diciendo lo mismo, y se soluciono borrando el caché. Igualmente muchas gracias por la respuesta!